# xcopy copying contents of two folders to different destinations

Tags: cmd, xcopy

I would like to copy 2 folders, desktop icons and favourites from a server location to the local public profile.

Example Structure: \localshare\user profile
2 folders in this directory Desktop and Favorites

My command at the moment is:

```
xcopy Desktop C:\Users\Default\Desktop
xcopy Favorites C:\Users\Public\Favorites
```

I assume if this is correct it will copy all the contents of the desktop and favourites folder to the destination. However I am not sure weather I need to specify *.* to include all the files inside? I also need to use %DP0% so I can change the command to the current working directory.

I would be grateful for any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can always type **xcopy /?** on a command prompt for help

From the looks of what you're trying to accomplish, I would say you want to copy all files AND folders.
I would do the following:

xcopy **\\servername**\Desktop C:\Users\Default\Desktop /r/i/c/h/k/e/y

xcopy **\\servername**\Favorites C:\Users\Public\Favorites /r/i/c/h/k/e/y

Just replace servername with the physical location of the files in the server and you should be good.

Hope that helps :)